# Android progressbar not spinning

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask

I got a Problem with a spinning progressbar. I start the ProgressDialog within a AsyncTask its comming up, but it does not spin.

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {         
        ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Within the following method the AsyncTask is started.

```
    public void login(View view) {

    new ProgressTask().execute(true);
    startActivityForResult((new Intent().setClass(view.getContext(), PPAClientActivity.class)), 0);
}
```

I didnt got any idea what i am doin wrong.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: are you purposely doing nothing in **doInBackground** of your AsyncTask? and why are you launching a new activity right after initiating AsyncTask? shouldn't you wait till the task is complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this way

```
 ProgressDialog dialog = new  ProgressDialog(YouractivityName.this);

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {         
     dialog.setTitle("Title");
    dialog.setMessage("Message");
   dialog.show();

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {   
 if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
      this.dialog.dismiss();
   }      
 startActivityForResult((new Intent().setClass(view.getContext(),PPAClientActivity.class)),0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the Intent line in the post execute method of AsycTask....

Then probably you won't face the problem...

Hope this is helpful